# Java 8 Defender Methods

Tags: java, methods, intellij-idea

After being very excited and optimistic about Java 8 "extension"/defender methods I am finding myself disappointed.  In reading what it does I was expecting to, like with C# or Scala, to be able to "insert" my own methods "onto" final/sealed classes.

One very simple requirement is to be able to "extend" String with my own method mid - in order to do something like this:
"123456".mid(2,2) => "34"

I really don't want to get into an academic argument about why this code design is bad.  It works for C#, it works for Scala, so why would this argument be any different for Java - rhetorically asking?

Currently one option to alleviate this is by doing the StringUtils.mid("123456", 2, 2)... which is really counter-intuitive imho.

I known lombok does this - but unfortunately it is not compatible with this specific feature for my IDE (IntelliJ).

Can somebody please direct me to code of where such a defender was done successfully if possible?  Googling it only gives examples of Collection API where the code is already written "into" JDK 8 or examples from the ground up for non-JDK or Sealed classes.

Regards,
Gawie

Comment: Could you explain how you would implement an interface into a final class? You would have to extend it?

Comment: Also, this is sort of entering into a discussion/asking for examples rather than asking a concrete solvable question

Comment: If you would be open to a suggestion: Check out the Xtend language - (it compiles into valid Java 1.6), which has this feature (extension methods are available even from a non-static context), and more. It's like java on steroids without forcing the functional stuff, like Scala. It also has good IDE support in eclipse, and is also coming for IDEA. I'm currently using it, and I'm having fun doing so.

Comment: Defender methods are *not* mixins/extension methods. You may have read about that, but all they do is solve *some* of the problems full mixins can solve.

Comment: Classes are declared `final` for a reason. If you want to do maximum-stuff-per-character and reducing 3 lines of code into 1 is important to you, then java is the wrong language - maybe perl is more your taste.

Comment: @vikingsteve Static helpers are not just a more verbose 1-for-1 replacement for extension methods: they are not subject to dynamic dispatch.

Comment: You are missing the crucial other half of the puzzle: interface injection (which has been proposed several times over the years, but doesn't exist yet). With interface injection *plus* default methods, you would get something like extension methods in C#, but default methods alone just give you safe upgrade paths for interfaces, or a way to do "lever interfaces" (i.e. interfaces which have only one abstract method upon which a whole host of powerful concrete methods are built, like Ruby's `Enumerable` which provides everything you want to do with a collection based on a single `each` method).

Comment: I think the better name is default methods. They have a default implementation in the Interface that you can override, but you don't have to.

Comment: First off - it probably is - by the answers that I am getting - not a concrete solvable question as it seems it is still not possible to do in Java.  Jorg - thanks - you answer it best.  I am looking for something that there is a closer notion of but still not implemented.  Thanks.  Bali - thanks - I actually did come across Xtend in my adventures of finding an answer.  I however, as much as I like intuitive code, really find fighting an IDE a waste of time - so until that time I will be quite sceptical of going the XTend route.

Comment: Not only fighting an IDE, but also overusing peripheral technologies to 'implement' shortcomings of a compiler/JDK.  And sorry, but the question is not how it should be done...  the first question is whether it is a worthwhile language feature...  and my vote is a simple YES!

Comment: @keuleJ: default methods is the name that appears in the Java 8 spec, but that was a very late change, for most of the time during the design phase, they were called (public) defender methods as in "if you cannot afford a lawyer, a public defender will be provided to you".

Comment: Thanks Jorg :-)  Any way I describe my disappointment with a 3+ year wait for a new version of Java, and the main opposition/other languages having had these features for what seems forever already while the new version does not - will be harshly dealt with by fan boys and trolls alike.  So I won't say it. Thanks for the info - I was hopeful that I was doing it wrong and that there was some magic way of achieving this now.  Thanks again for clearing that up.

Comment: Should this question perhaps be re-titled to "Can Java 8 default methods be used as mixins?"  (Answer: no.)